# как работает ssl прокси?

Tags: linux, proxy

почитал код `tinyproxy`, но так и не понял как он работает с ssl. я делал для теста свой прокси и обычные запросы шли на прокси, а ssl тоже шли, но я не понимаю как понять куда идут ssl, если трафик зашифрован. хотел почитать RFC, ну может какой нибудь есть по proxy, и написав это в моей программе я увидел очень много документов и не знаю, есть ли среди них тот самый, который описывает протокол.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в https сообщениях есть не шифрованное имя хоста, на который клиент обращается - [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)  RFC 3546